# React Native Animated API custom component runs animation but doesnt update the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Trying out the Animated API for the first time and I am stumped. I am trying to animate the action of applying a linear gradient on a button when pressed, and removing it when unpressed. I am using react-native-linear-gradient to apply gradients. I cannot get the animation to show up though. I know it runs on press as it shows partially if I forcibly update the state on button press. Here is my code so far:

I have added the code here:https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shape-mvcdt5?file=/src/Button.tsx

I am not sure if I need to do anything to trigger a UI update. I used a simple Animated.View and changed opacity to check if animations worked at all, and that worked fine. createAnimatedComponent is where I am stuck at unfortunately.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.